# Need help confirming answer to this stokes theorem question

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

I'm trying to solve this question in preparation for my upcoming uni subject, i believe i understand it properly but im not quite sure, would like some assurance or guidance.

(a) Use Stokes Theorem to Evaluate
$$\int\int_s\triangledown\times F\cdot dS$$
Where
$$F=yz\hat i-xy \hat j+\hat k$$
and S is the hemisphere $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=4$ with $z\geq 1$ oriented upward

My answer is $-4\pi$ (working below) can someone confirm if this is correct, if not why. Thanks.

$$x^2+y^2+(1-1)^2=4$$
$$x^{2}+y^{2}=4$$
$$r(t)=<2cos(t),2sin(t),0>$$
$$F=[2sin(t)(1)\hat i-2cos(t)\cdot 2sin(t)+1]$$
giving
$$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\left[((2\sin t)(-2\sin t))-(2\cos t\cdot 2\sin t)(2\cos t)\right]dt$$
and then solving this to get $$-4\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

- Somehow you end up calculating the right integral
  but for the life of me I don't understand your expression
  $F=[2sin(t)(1)\hat i-2cos(t)\cdot 2sin(t)+1]\,.$
- A correct way of naming the theorem is "the Stokes theorem" or "Stokes' theorem".
- A reader friendly solution would tell us that you are calculating the line integral of $F$ over the boundary of the hemisphere. Have you thought about orientation? Why is the result not $+4\pi\,?$
- It would not hurt to say a few words why the correct equation for that boundary is $x^2+y^2=4\,.$
- With the parametrization $t\mapsto \gamma(t):=(r\cos t,r\sin t,1)$ of that boundary $(r=2)$ the line integral is then

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}F(\gamma(t))\cdot \dot \gamma(t)\,dt&=\int_0^{2\pi}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}r\sin t\\-r^2\cos t\sin t\\1\end{pmatrix}}_{\begin{pmatrix}yz\\-xy\\1\end{pmatrix}}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-r\sin t\\r\cos t\\0\end{pmatrix}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}-r^2\sin^2 t-r^3\cos^2 t\sin t\,dt=-r^2\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2t\,dt\\
&=-4\pi\,. 
 \end{align}